# Prevent duplicate values into mysql database - if certain colums are similar to the last inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, latitude-longitude

Hi I'm inserting Latitude, Longitude values into the database.

```
INSERT INTO `Tracks` (`Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Time`, `Date`, `Speed`) VALUES ('$Latitude', '$Longitude', '$UTC_Time', '$UTC_Date', '$Speed');
```

The gps receiver tends to send the same lat, long values more than once.. Before inserting, i'm trying to check the lat long columns of the last inserted row, and if they match, the query should not be executed. Else the query should be executed. I'm currently unable to do this! What if there are no rows in the database and the code checks for the last inserted row?

Also the user may come to the same location again at a later time and hence we should not check the whole db for duplicate lat, long values. How should I do this then? Can I do this in php itself without checking the db? Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would do this in PHP, as you suggested. If you have a session, simply store the last value there.

Comment: Hey how should I do it? Like this? if($_SESSION['Latitude'] == $Latitude && $_SESSION['Longitude'] == $Longitude) { $_SESSION['Latitude'] = $Latitude; $_SESSION['Longitude'] = $Longitude; }
else
{query}

what is the initial value of $_SESSION['Latitude'] and $_SESSION['Longitude']..??

Comment: That code is fine. Initially, the value will be undefined (NULL). After the query, also set the session variable.

Comment: Yup thank you very much! I'd accept this as answer but this is a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MySQL, one thing I can think of is to change

> `INSERT INTO`Tracks`(`Latitude`,`Longitude`,`Time`,`Speed`) > VALUES ('$Latitude', '$Longitude', '$UTC_Time', '$UTC_Date',
>   '$Speed');`

into

> `INSERT IGNORE INTO`Tracks`(`Latitude`,`Longitude`,`Time`,`Speed`) > VALUES ('$Latitude', '$Longitude', '$UTC_Time', '$UTC_Date',
>   '$Speed');`

And setting a `PRIMARY KEY` with those two fields (Latitude and Longitude).

Since you specified `without checking the db` is the only solution I can think of.
If you try to insert an equal pair of `Langitude, Latitude` `INSERT IGNORE` statement will be just ignored.

Comment: yea! But  when the user comes to the same place after some time, I may try to insert the same lat long values.. I this case, the values has to be inserted and should not be ignored!

Comment: That can be workarrounded by adding some field to the primary key, example, hacing lat, long and date, will prevent you that duplicates within the same day.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this in php itself without checking the db?

If you want to check if the value allready exists you're going to have to query the database one way or the other.

You can do a `SELECT` on the last record and compare it's value in PHP, or you can try and insert the value into the database and if the value allready exists you choose to ignore the insert.

Comment: no.. We can try to put the lat long values in some temporary php variable and check them against the new lat long values. If they match the query won't be executed. The only problem here is how would I initialize the temp variables?!

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE instead of insert. You will have to make the collumn wich has to be unique unique in the database.

In addition, the way you're using mysql is a huge security risk.
The least you can do is use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Better yet is to take a look at prepared statements.

Comment: The table need not be unique... U can come to the same place any number of times. If the column is unique.. it would say you have come to the place only once...